# Order multiple images by filename in Active storage Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have has_many_attached images relationship in Post model. I want to order the images by their filename when showing them on the Post show page. How can I order by filename?

Example:

```
<% @post.images.order("id DESC").each do |image| %>
```

Is it possible to just order by filename through something like active_storage_blob.filename or something?

Comment: Maybe you could try `post.images.joins(:blob).order('active_storage_blobs.filename ASC')`?

Comment: Perfect @engineersmnky. Need to up my joins game. That worked. Fair play. Make it an answer and i'll confirm it correct dude. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you add the has_many_attached macro to a class it actually adds the following relationships to your class

```
  class Post < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :image_attachments, -> { where(name: 'image') }, class_name: "ActiveStorage::Attachment", as: :record, inverse_of: :record, dependent: false
     has_many :image_blobs, through: :image_attachments, class_name: "ActiveStorage::Blob", source: :blob
  end
```

This means we can leverage the relationship to handle sorting by `filename` which is actually an attribute of the `ActiveStorage::Blob` rather than the attachment. To do this we reference to the relation defined in by the macro `images` in your case and then `join` to its natural relationship to the `ActiveStorage::Blob` so that we can sort based on these fields.

The final result would be

```
   <% @post.images.joins(:blobs).order('active_storage_blobs.filename ASC').each do |image| %>
```

Now all of the images will be sorted by the filename however since joins does not actually load any data and I am assuming you are referencing the the file name in your view we could also use

```
   <% @post.images.includes(:blobs).references(:blobs).order('active_storage_blobs.filename ASC').each do |image| %>
```

To have a single query that loads the images and the `ActiveStorage::Blob` data all at once to avoid the n + 1 issues that could arise from the original version.

Comment: i think this is now something like `@post.images_attachments.joins(:blob)...`

Answer (score 3):

For Rails 6 I needed

```rb
@post.images.includes(:blob).references(:blob).order('active_storage_blobs.filename ASC').each do |image|
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is googling for **general** solution how to reorder `has_many_attached` attachments you can do it by adding a Array/JSON-Array/Serialized field to the model which declares the `has_many_attached` and store ids of ActiveStorage::Attachment in order. Then you can do something like:

```
# app/models/entry.rb
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :pictures


  def ordered_pictures
    pictures.sort_by{ |pic| ordered_picture_ids.index(pic.id) || (pic.id*100) }
  end

  def ordered_picture_ids=(ids)
    super(ids.map(&:to_i)) # convert any ids passed to this method to integer
                           # this is just for security reasons,
                           # you don't need to do this for the feature to work
  end
end
```

If you have no idea what I mean by that I wrote more detailed article on this: https://blog.eq8.eu/article/order-attachments-in-rails-activestorage-has_many_attached.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have the class setup with ActiveStorage like:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images
end
```

You can run this to order and avoid N+1 queries

```
@post.images.includes(:blob).references(:blob).order(:filename)
```