# Rails Active Storage, querying models against their blob filenames

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

How can you query against Active Storage blob filenames?

Basically looking for all the join shortcuts that are not obvious.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order multiple images by filename in Active storage Rails 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539534/order-multiple-images-by-filename-in-active-storage-rails-5-2)

Comment: @engineersmnky not really, because i'm looking for the record objects, not the attachment/blob objects. So i'm filtering the top-level record by its blob filename

Comment: In that post the OP was looking for the `Image` objects (not the blobs themselves). I was simply pointing you there because it shows how to join an object to the blobs and explains how the "has attached" macro works to create those joins , which appeared to be your question.

Answer (score 2):

From Blair Anderson examples but using Arel syntax

```
filename_substring = "2023"

# has_one_attached :backup
Report.joins(:backup_blob).where(ActiveStorage::Blob.arel_table[:filename].matches("%#{filename_substring}%"))

# has_many_attached :backups
Report.joins(:backups_blobs).where(ActiveStorage::Blob.arel_table[:filename].matches("%#{filename_substring}%"))
```

Comment: Upvote for [tag:arel] usage.

Answer (score 1):

I Figured this out...

**has_one_attached**:

```rb
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :backup
end
```

Then you can query blobs:

```rb
Report.joins(:backup_blob).where("active_storage_blobs.filename LIKE ?", "%query%").count
```

**has_many_attached**:

```rb
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :backups
end
```

Then you can query blobs:

```rb
Report.joins(:backups_blobs).where("active_storage_blobs.filename LIKE ?", "%query%").count
```

You can also query blobs by `content_type`, `byte_size` and `checksum`